# How to put a div over another div or element, but have it be 50% of that div (trying to do click event)

Tags: html, css

Basically, I've been trying all sorts of positioning and what not, but here's the issue:

given one div that is shaped like a rectangle, I am trying to overlay another div on it that will be 50% of the width.  However, if I do this then the div below also changes its shape/positioning.

How can I prevent htis from happening?

I know how to make containers, but the inside content is bound by the outer content.

In this case, I want to put a smaller div on top of a larger dive without messing up the div below.

```
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks to both of you but unfortunately I ended up not doing this :(  Both of your solutions worked though.

Answer (score 2):

What if you contain them in another div?
Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.container {
    height: 300px;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
}
div.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    bottom: 0px;
    display:block;
} 

div.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 3px solid #73AD21;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>position: absolute;</h2>

<p>An element with position: absolute; is positioned relative to the nearest positioned ancestor (instead of positioned relative to the viewport, like fixed):</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="overlay">This div element has position: relative;
    <div class="image">This div element has position: absolute;</div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FE87FF3WRXHF

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout this fiddle, if I understand you correctly

you can either use

```
float:left
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wuvxuddk/

to take the div out of the normal flow or use

```
position: absolute
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tygpoxuk/